# RPN Calculator assignment 2, descriptionOfProgram

Tags: objective-c, ios, calculator

i have been working on this assignment for 6 days so far, i feel frustrated specially cus i don't have more ideas or way to do what the assignment want.

I am at description of program part ( I have started with it, haven't done the rest of assignment parts ), i am confused of what to do. Here is my current implementation.

```
+(NSString *)descriptionOfProgram:(id)program
{
if (![self isValidProgram:program]) 
    return @"Invalid program!";
NSMutableArray *stack = [program mutableCopy];
return [self descriptionHelper:stack];
}
+(NSString *)descriptionHelper:(NSMutableArray *)stack
{
NSString *result;
id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];
if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) 
{
   result = [topOfStack stringValue];
}
else if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@ %@)",[self descriptionHelper:stack],topOfStack,[self descriptionHelper:stack]];
    return result = [self bracketHandler:result];
}
return result;
}
+(NSString *)bracketHandler:(NSString *)stringWithBrackets
{
int lengthOfString = [stringWithBrackets length];
NSString *newString = stringWithBrackets;
if (lengthOfString < 8)
{
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
}
else 
{
    <#statements#>
}
return newString;
}
```

I am stuck at this point, i know that my current implementation seems suck, but i want just a small guidance of where to move, what to look for, how to actually finish this task and display a human readable description of my program all time, with minimum number of brackets and logical way.

Please i would really appreciate just a small push in the right direction, i am so lost.

Comment: I want to format my program every time it changes to logical format, say my input is 2, 3, 5, +, *, it should print 2 * (3+5), thats what i am trying to achieve, with all the possible cases.
I want to know where to start, cus i am kinda lost of where to begin, what method will help me, should i manipulate with NSStrings? or array? how condition should i look for to start doing my if cases, i am just lost i need a small direction to start this.
Specially that i want to do it in recursion, makes it a bit more challenging.

Comment: How about googling for this "C++ RPN calculator"?

Comment: Nothing regarding how to describe whats in the stack, they just implement it, which i have no problem with.

Simply, forget that its calculator, i just want to do string manipulation thats all, some kind of algorithm to get me the desired output, I am not asking for complete solution, i just want a point to start with. Or any kind of assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand what your problem is. **If** you have difficulties to determine what type of data your string represents, you might try to create a character set (`NSCharacterSet* yourSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:yourString]`) and test, if this set is a subset of a standard set your provide, e.g.:

```
if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] isSupersetOfSet: yourSet]) { 
   /* integer number */
} else if ([[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*/"] isSupersetOfSet: yourSet]) {
   /* multiplication or division */
} else ...
```

This might not be the most elegant solution, however it is easy to apply and should work.